# Updating Column value based on another column value in Spotfire

Tags: pie-chart, spotfire

I wish to create a drop down menu in Spotfire using 5 values.
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
where Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 and Col5 are column headers in my data sheet.

I am creating a Pie Diagram visualization.

Now, based on my selection Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 and Col5, I wish to select another column in the Color by: property for the pie.
For example: If I select Col1 then I should get "Col1 Complete" value in Color by: property for the pie. If I select Col2 then I should get "Col2 Complete" value in Color by: property which is another column in the data set.

I was able to create a drop down list using Property Control with the Col1-Col5 values in the list. However, I am unable to handle second part where based on my selection of Col, I need the Color by: property value to change to "Col Complete"

Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with a Document Property:

1. create a **Drop-down list** Property Control in a Textarea
2. under **Set property value through:** choose **Column selection**, then choose the correct data table
3. click **New** to create a String Document Property called PieColorBy with a starting value of `Col1`.
4. open the Properties dialog for the visualization you want to change and access the Colors page
5. set a Custom Expression like `[${PieColorBy} Complete]`. notice that `Complete` is not in quotes.
6. change the drop-down list to test

Comment: Hi Niko, Thank you for your response. It worked correctly. However, there are just two values that a "Col1 Complete" column can have. 1. Complete 2. Incomplete. So based on the selection, I wish the Complete value = Green and Incomplete value = Red. But, when I switch the values in the drop down, the color does not set to Green, Red. I added a Rule which says, Equal to 'Complete' then Green but it does not retain the colors and changes back to default. Can you kindly advice?